# Android ContextMenu to change button text

Tags: java, android, listview, contextmenu, adapter

Here's my problem:

I have a button in my android application that when I longClick it a context menu appears with a list of values that a user can choose from.

What I need to do is when the user chooses a value, I need the button's text to be that value. I can't figure out how to get the onContextItemSelected listener to remember which button triggered the context menu and then set it's text to the selected item.

Thanks for any help/tips you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)?

Comment: What ended up happening was I resolved an issue with inner classes in my program as I was assigning onLongClick listeners to my buttons inside a for loop. I just copied the variables I needed to use (the button and the index of the for loop) and assigned them as "final".

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, I believe you can do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  View longClickedView = info.targetView;
  ...
}
```